# добавление данных из INPUT в список, без отправки на сервер

Tags: javascript, jquery

Работаю с таблицей. Есть *select*, для демонстрации выпадающего списка данных (подгружаются с сервера). Есть *input* - ввод пользователем данных. После нажатия на ENTER появляется новая строка с введенными из *input* данными, введены они в новую ячейку таблицы(без отправки их на сервер).
Как, без отправки данных на сервер, добавить их из *input* в выпадающий список?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
$("form").submit(function (e) {
  e.preventDefault()
  $("select").append($("<option>").text($("input").val()))
})
```

```html
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form><input required><button>Add</button></form>
<p><select><option>1<option>2<option>3</select>
```

Comment: А если поле для ввода и выпадающий список находятся в разных таблицах?

Comment: Какая разница? Просто подставь правильные селекторы (вероятно, по id).